# VBA query Inserting Time instead of Date

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I need some help with my query I am trying to insert to a table see above code:

```
CurrentDb.Execute ("INSERT INTO tblWarehouseItem ( whiwrhID, whiItemName, whivatName," whiVatRate, whiimtID, whiQty, whiPrice, whisupID, whiDateIn, whiExpiryDate,whiwhiID ) " & _
                                   " Values (" & rs!WID & "," & Chr(34) & rs!N & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & rs!VN & Chr(34) & "," & rs!VR & "," & rs!IID & "," & intQtyForm & "," & rs!PR & "," & rs!SID & "," & CDate(rs!DIN) & "," & CDate(rs!EXD) & "," & rs!ID & ")")
```

In my table the `CDate(rs!EXD)` and `CDate(rs!DIN)` are stored as time.

When I compile my query in the immediate window I get Dates.

```
INSERT INTO tblWarehouseItem ( whiwrhID, whiItemName, whivatName, whiVatRate, whiimtID, whiQty, whiPrice, whisupID, whiDateIn, whiExpiryDate,whiwhiID )  Values (2,"ITEM10","A",19,14,4,20,10,21/07/14,26/05/14,60)
```

How can I make my query to insert the date in the table?

thanks in advance

Comment: is there a particular reason you are using a recordset to populate the query instead of doing a `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` which would sidestep this entire problem? Or, you can `Format(rs!DIN,'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM')` or, `TimeValue()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run that `21/07/14` is passed to Access and interpreted as an integer resulting from `12 divide by 7 divide by 14` which when converted to a date is just a time.

Delimit dates with `#`:

```
.. ",#" & CDate(rs!DIN) & "#," ..
```